# How to retrieve/compute an X509 certificate's thumbprint in Java?

Tags: java, certificate

I have a java client that is calling a web service operation which takes a certificate "thumbprint" as a parameter. I believe the thumbprint is some kind of SHA1 hash, in hexadecimal string format, of the cert's public key, but I'm not sure.

The .NET framework seems to include a simple way to get this value ([X509Certificate2.Thumbprint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.thumbprint.aspx) property). Viewing a .cer file's properties in Windows also displays the thumbprint, which looks like:

```
a6 9c fd b0 58 0d a4 ee ae 9a 47 75 24 c3 0b 9f 5d b6 1c 77
```

My question is therefore: Does anybody know how to retrieve or compute this thumbprint string within Java, if I have an instance of a [java.security.cert.X509Certificate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/security/cert/X509Certificate.html)?

Comment: This Java demo (URLConnection) program connects to a https url and prints/calculates all kinds of fingerprints, including pin-sha256, SKI and Thumbprints: https://github.com/ecki/JavaCryptoTest/blob/master/src/main/java/net/eckenfels/test/ssl/UrlInspect.java

Answer (score 85, accepted):

The SHA-1 hash of the [DER encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.690#DER_encoding) of the certificate is what .NET is getting with **X509Certificate2.Thumbprint**.

As noted on the [remarks on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.thumbprint.aspx#Remarks):

> The thumbprint is dynamically generated using the SHA1 algorithm and does not physically exist in the certificate. Since the thumbprint is a unique value for the certificate, it is commonly used to find a particular certificate in a certificate store.

Java's standard library doesn't provide the thumbprint directly, but you can get it like this:

```
DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(
        MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1").digest(
                cert.getEncoded())).toLowerCase();
```

Here's a full worked example using a conveniently accessible PEM file:

1. Create **stackoverflow.crt.pem**:

   ```
   -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
   MIIHHjCCBgagAwIBAgIQDhG71w1UtxDQxvVAtrUspDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBw
   MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEVMBMGA1UEChMMRGlnaUNlcnQgSW5jMRkwFwYDVQQLExB3
   d3cuZGlnaWNlcnQuY29tMS8wLQYDVQQDEyZEaWdpQ2VydCBTSEEyIEhpZ2ggQXNz
   dXJhbmNlIFNlcnZlciBDQTAeFw0xNjA1MjEwMDAwMDBaFw0xOTA4MTQxMjAwMDBa
   MGoxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMQswCQYDVQQIEwJOWTERMA8GA1UEBxMITmV3IFlvcmsx
   HTAbBgNVBAoTFFN0YWNrIEV4Y2hhbmdlLCBJbmMuMRwwGgYDVQQDDBMqLnN0YWNr
   ZXhjaGFuZ2UuY29tMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAr0YD
   zscT5i6T2FaRsTGNCiLB8OtPXu8N9iAyuaROh/nS0kRRsN8wUMk1TmgZhPuYM6oF
   S377V8W2LqhLBMrPXi7lnhvKt2DFWCyw38RrDbEsM5dzVGErmhux3F0QqcTI92zj
   VW61DmE7NSQLiR4yonVpTpdAaO4jSPJxn8d+4p1sIlU2JGSk8LZSWFqaROc7KtXt
   lWP4HahNRZtdwvL5dIEGGNWx+7B+XVAfY1ygc/UisldkA+a3D2+3WAtXgFZRZZ/1
   CWFjKWJNMAI6ZBAtlbgSNgRYxdcdleIhPLCzkzWysfltfiBmsmgz6VCoFR4KgJo8
   Gd3MeTWojBthM10SLwIDAQABo4IDuDCCA7QwHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUUWj/kK8CB3U8
   zNllZGKiErhZcjswHQYDVR0OBBYEFFrBQmPCYhOznZSEqjIeF8tto4Z7MIIB6AYD
   VR0RBIIB3zCCAduCEyouc3RhY2tleGNoYW5nZS5jb22CEXN0YWNrb3ZlcmZsb3cu
   Y29tghMqLnN0YWNrb3ZlcmZsb3cuY29tgg1zdGFja2F1dGguY29tggtzc3RhdGlj
   Lm5ldIINKi5zc3RhdGljLm5ldIIPc2VydmVyZmF1bHQuY29tghEqLnNlcnZlcmZh
   dWx0LmNvbYINc3VwZXJ1c2VyLmNvbYIPKi5zdXBlcnVzZXIuY29tgg1zdGFja2Fw
   cHMuY29tghRvcGVuaWQuc3RhY2thdXRoLmNvbYIRc3RhY2tleGNoYW5nZS5jb22C
   GCoubWV0YS5zdGFja2V4Y2hhbmdlLmNvbYIWbWV0YS5zdGFja2V4Y2hhbmdlLmNv
   bYIQbWF0aG92ZXJmbG93Lm5ldIISKi5tYXRob3ZlcmZsb3cubmV0gg1hc2t1YnVu
   dHUuY29tgg8qLmFza3VidW50dS5jb22CEXN0YWNrc25pcHBldHMubmV0ghIqLmJs
   b2dvdmVyZmxvdy5jb22CEGJsb2dvdmVyZmxvdy5jb22CGCoubWV0YS5zdGFja292
   ZXJmbG93LmNvbYIVKi5zdGFja292ZXJmbG93LmVtYWlsghNzdGFja292ZXJmbG93
   LmVtYWlsMA4GA1UdDwEB/wQEAwIFoDAdBgNVHSUEFjAUBggrBgEFBQcDAQYIKwYB
   BQUHAwIwdQYDVR0fBG4wbDA0oDKgMIYuaHR0cDovL2NybDMuZGlnaWNlcnQuY29t
   L3NoYTItaGEtc2VydmVyLWc1LmNybDA0oDKgMIYuaHR0cDovL2NybDQuZGlnaWNl
   cnQuY29tL3NoYTItaGEtc2VydmVyLWc1LmNybDBMBgNVHSAERTBDMDcGCWCGSAGG
   /WwBATAqMCgGCCsGAQUFBwIBFhxodHRwczovL3d3dy5kaWdpY2VydC5jb20vQ1BT
   MAgGBmeBDAECAjCBgwYIKwYBBQUHAQEEdzB1MCQGCCsGAQUFBzABhhhodHRwOi8v
   b2NzcC5kaWdpY2VydC5jb20wTQYIKwYBBQUHMAKGQWh0dHA6Ly9jYWNlcnRzLmRp
   Z2ljZXJ0LmNvbS9EaWdpQ2VydFNIQTJIaWdoQXNzdXJhbmNlU2VydmVyQ0EuY3J0
   MAwGA1UdEwEB/wQCMAAwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQADggEBAAzJAMGSdKoX1frdqNlN
   iXu8Gcbsm/DxWMXpcTXlZn8s+/qQQoc+/3o0CK3C8/j9n5DmsYa88P6Ntt5ysDs+
   b0ynXFva4CAEyKaoPM4SIpOjwfWBRSUOqAIkQO2/LhKBwT/EnpaIHIKGnI0UdXLQ
   oDfkMDg6mgJsEBsKdKF5EfEX7iU3NO5xVJPJE8/R0btLAdYwxB9S6fSpCXGe2HqQ
   D101O/7/4MWNdFSbfdDSFcn5oEm+idimrqiNrF5knmuJy4qPBkL7thNuGK6rvYCF
   ZJM03ZEZhkQmn2jG/7LgjfwZmvfcITeADCpylf88bL+lf+vxe6cCl9CyqWgBDpsI
   xpE=
   -----END CERTIFICATE-----
   ```
2. Create **X509.java**:

   ```
   import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
   import java.io.FileInputStream;
   import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
   import java.security.MessageDigest;
   import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
   import java.security.cert.CertificateEncodingException;
   import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
   import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
   import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

   public final class X509 {
       public static void main(String[] args)
               throws FileNotFoundException, CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
           FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
           CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
           X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) certificateFactory.generateCertificate(is);
           String thumbprint = getThumbprint(cert);
           System.out.println(thumbprint);
       }

       private static String getThumbprint(X509Certificate cert)
               throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateEncodingException {
           MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
           byte[] der = cert.getEncoded();
           md.update(der);
           byte[] digest = md.digest();
           String digestHex = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(digest);
           return digestHex.toLowerCase();
       }
   }
   ```
3. Compile the program with Java 8:

   ```
   javac X509.java
   ```

   Or Java 9 - due to modular JDK/JPMS - **DataTypeConverter** is not in **java.base**, but **java.xml.bind**, so you need to explicitly depend on it during your build:

   ```
   javac --add-modules java.xml.bind X509.java
   ```

   Otherwise, on Java 9, you get this when you try to build it:

   ```
   X509.java:3: error: package javax.xml.bind is not visible
           import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
           ^
           (package javax.xml.bind is declared in module java.xml.bind, which is not in the module graph)
           1 error
   ```
4. Run it with Java 8:

   ```
   java X509 stackoverflow.crt.pem
   ```

   In Java 9 - due to modular JDK/JPMS - **DataTypeConverter** is not in **java.base**, but **java.xml.bind**, so you need to explicitly depend on it when running your program:

   ```
   java --add-modules java.xml.bind X509 stackoverflow.crt.pem
   ```

   Otherwise, on Java 9, you get this when you try to run it:

   ```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter
       at X509.getThumbPrint(X509.java:29)
       at X509.main(X509.java:19)
       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter
       at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
       at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
       at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
       ... 2 more
   ```
5. Get the expected output:

   ```
   47adb03649a2eb18f63ffa29790818349a99cab7
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Googling around I found that the thumbprint is commonly used as a unique identifier for a certificate, so it doesn't seem to be .NET specific. The web service I'm calling is using it to find the certificate in their store.

Comment: The web service must be a .NET server. I haven't seen any other servers using thumbprint to store client cert. .NET made so much security-related extensions, you might encounter other issues also. Unless your client needs to be cross-platform, it would be a lot easier to write client in .NET too.

Comment: Thumbprints aren't .Net exclusive. Have you tried connecting to a server using SSH that you haven't connected to before? You'll see its thumbprint. The certificate store will have thumbprints listed, too.

Comment: "Why do you need it in Java?" - He's probably pinning the certificate. Its much safer than trusting any of the hundreds of CA and subordinate CAs and DNS.

Comment: Since Java 17 instead of using `DataTypeConverter` you can use [`java.util.HexFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HexFormat.html) (this also allows customizing the format of the hex string)

Answer (score 52):

Using Apache Commons Codec you can do:

```
DigestUtils.sha1Hex(cert.getEncoded())
```

Answer (score 6):

One-liner using Google's [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava)

```
Hashing.sha256().hashBytes(cert.getEncoded()).toString();
```

Comment: For completeness - commonly SHA-1 (`Hashing.sha1()`) is used as thumbprint (as seen in the other answers).

Comment: sha1 is deprecated in Guava

Answer (score 2):

You can generate the thumbprint by using the openssl command, so example if you have the pem format of the certificate in a file (file.txt)

then:

`cat file.txt | openssl x509 -sha1 -fingerprint` - this would generate the same thumbprint

Comment: How does that help with Java?

Answer (score 0):

Short example without using any libraries.

```
object MessageDigestUtil {

    private val hexCode = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray()

    fun sha1(input: ByteArray): ByteArray {
        return digest(input,"SHA-1")
    }

    @Throws(NoSuchAlgorithmException::class)
    fun getFingerprint(publicKey: PublicKey): String? {
        return printHexBinary(sha1(publicKey.encoded))
    }

    private fun printHexBinary(data: ByteArray): String {
        val r = StringBuilder(data.size * 2)
        for (b in data) {
            r.append(hexCode[b.toInt() shr 4 and 0xF])
            r.append(hexCode[(b and 0xF).toInt()])
        }
        return r.toString()
    }

    @Throws(NoSuchAlgorithmException::class)
    private fun digest(input: ByteArray, algorithm: String): ByteArray {
        val digest = MessageDigest.getInstance(algorithm)
        digest.update(input)
        return digest.digest()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you stumbled to this thread while having problems how to generate the correct thumbprint for MSGraph API which is base64 encoded [as stated in this document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/certificate-credentials)

This will generate correct x5t header parameter.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateEncodingException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.util.Base64;

X509Certificate cert = getPublicKey();

String thumbprint = getThumbprint(cert); // base64 encoded thumbprint
    
X509Certificate getPublicKey() {
    try (FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream("{your .crt or .cer file here}")) {

        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(inStream);

        return cert;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("no file!");
        return null;
    }
}

String getThumbprint(X509Certificate cert) {
    try {
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(getHash(cert));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}

static byte[] getHash(X509Certificate cert) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateEncodingException {
    final MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    md.update(cert.getEncoded());
    return md.digest();
}
```