# Client identification over SSL

Tags: ssl, jakarta-ee, authorization

Which of the following is more appropriate to use as an identification field in a database to represent a client, when two-way SSL authentication is used?

1. The client's X500Principal

   OR
2. The [thumbprint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270703/how-to-retrieve-compute-an-x509-certificates-thumbprint-in-java) of the client's certificate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is appropriate depends on what you are doing with the authentication information, but in general I would guess that you want to use the subject distinguished name (DN) which you can retrieve with the [`java.security.cert.X509Certificate.getSubjectX500Principal`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/cert/X509Certificate.html#getSubjectX500Principal%28%29) method.

The thumbprint will change when the certificate expires and the user renews it, but of course the user's identity will remain the same.

Comment: Thanks. I'd be using it for authorization purposes. The server will, for example, keep a mapping of clients to operations, and refer to that list to determine whether a particular client is allowed to perform a certain operation. Will the Subject DN be unique enough for this purpose?

Comment: It should be unique, but you'll have to ask the certificate authority what they do in the case of two different people with identical names.